# How to make view's board like tear from the paper?

Tags: ios, uiview, layer

I want to make the view's board like tear from the paper(in the picture) by code ,but I don't have any idea.Please help me!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this a UIView using `CALayer`’s *mask* property for the torn edges, and using a `UIBezierPath` with CALayer’s *shadowPath* for the shadow.

Drawing something like this with shadows and transparency will be relatively slow. Of course the other (and perhaps easier) approach would be to use a static background image created in Photoshop or something similar.

See here for details on [drawing using BezierPaths](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html)

[Drawing on Transparency layers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_trans_layers/dq_trans_layers.html)